# windowsのバッチで文字列のStartWith関数を実装したい

Tags: windows, batch-file

## 困っている事

与えられた文字列が`foo\bar`に合致していれば、`result=1`として、合致していなければ、`result=0`としたいです。
しかし、結果がすべて`result=0`になってしまいます。

## 想定している結果（例）

```
foo\bar\foo -> result = 1
foo\bar\hoge\hoge -> result =1
bar\foo\foo -> result = 0
foo\foo\foo -> result = 0
hoge\hoge -> result = 0
```

## 環境

- windows 7

## バッチファイル

```
@echo off
set FILE_PATH_TXT=%1
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%a in (%FILE_PATH_TXT%) do (
    call :startWithSrcPkgDir %%a
    echo !result!
)
endlocal

:startWithSrcPkgDir
echo !%1! > nul findstr /rx ^foo\\bar.* && set result=1 || set result=0
exit /b
```

※　%FILE_PATH_TXT% には、`c:\hoge\hoge.txt`のようなテキストファイルが渡されます。
※　テキストファイルの中身は

```
foo\bar\foo
foo\bar\hoge\hoge
bar\foo\foo
foo\foo\foo
hoge\hoge
```

のような形になっています。

## 参考サイト

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707742/windows-batch-check-if-variable-starts-with-ends-with-and-contains-a-specific-s

Comment: VBScrip かJScript を使ってみては？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findstrって...文字列渡せるんですかね？

ヘルプを見る限りだと、ファイルパスやディレクトリパスを渡す仕様に見えます。
なので、もし、任意のファイルを1行ずつ判断したければ...

1行取り出す → 一時ファイルに出力する → 一時ファイルをfindstrで評価する → 結果を出力する

を繰り返さないとダメなんではないでしょうか？

---

これでどうでしょ～？

```
@echo off
set FILE_PATH_TXT=%1
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%a in (%FILE_PATH_TXT%) do (
    call :startWithSrcPkgDir %%a
    echo !result!
)
endlocal

:startWithSrcPkgDir
echo %1 | findstr /rx ^foo\\bar.* 1>nul && set result=1 || set result=0
exit /b
```

Comment: 参考サイトではファイル出力してなくても出来ているようなのですが・・・。最悪はファイル出力を考えていますが、できればスマートに行きたいなと思いました。

Comment: @digdagdag う～ん、確かに標準入力からできそうなこと書いてありますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました！

Answer (score 2):

こんな感じ？

```
@echo off
set FILE_PATH_TXT=%1
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%a in (%FILE_PATH_TXT%) do (
    call :startWithSrcPkgDir %%a
    echo !result!
)
endlocal

:startWithSrcPkgDir
echo %1 | findstr /b "foo\\bar" > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (set result=1) ELSE (set result=0)
exit /b
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらでもできました！